# Как выгрузить данные из JSON в Гугл Таблицу

Tags: javascript, json

Имеется информация в JSON формате получаемая с https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries.
Необходимо с помощью скрипта загрузить и упорядочить в гугл таблицу.

```js
function processXMRAPI() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1v2NmYXtURFR3cnrhmuzrcFX48YQTLGRO8Nq4dkL4l1w');

  var APIPullSheet = ss.getSheetByName("APIPull");
  APIPullSheet.getRange('A1:M300').clearContent();

  var url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries";
  var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

  var results = [
    []
  ];

  for (var i in parcedData.result) {
    results[0].push(parcedData.result[i]);
  }

  resultRange = APIPullSheet.getRange(1, 1, results.length, 13);
  resultRange.setValues(results);
}
```

Вот как выглядит при этом массив
https://i.stack.imgur.com/URPRH.jpg

Обращаем внимание на то, что в JSON имеется 259 объектов и в каждом из них по 13 данных которые и надо расставить по ячейкам.
При выше указанном коде вылазит ошибка **Неправильная ширина диапазона: указано 259, должно быть 13 (строка 20, файл Код)**
20 это последняя строка кода.

Если не долго думая поменяем в 19 строке 13 на 259
resultRange = APIPullSheet.getRange(1, 1, results.length, 13);
то выгрузка происходит, не так как надо. Вид на следующей картинке
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MntBE.jpg

Видимо я не правильно разбираю массив, подскажите как это сделать, что бы данные заполнялись в 259 строк и 13 столбцов?

Answer (score 1):

**Вопрос решен.** В коде моего скрипта был применен метод работы с одномерным массивом

```html
var results = [[]];
for(var i in parcedData.result)
{
  results[0].push(parcedData.result[i]);
}
```

, а получаемая информация JSON представлена в виде многомерного массива и работать с ним нужно было, как показано в  коде ниже:

```html
var results = new Array ();
  for(var i in parcedData.result)
    {
      var temp = [];
      for(var j in parcedData.result[i])
      {
        temp.push(parcedData.result[i][j]);
      }
      results.push(temp);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function processXMRAPI() 
{

 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1v2NmYXtURFR3cnrhmuzrcFX48YQTLGRO8Nq4dkL4l1w');  



  var APIPullSheet = ss.getSheetByName ("APIPull");
  APIPullSheet.getRange ('A1:M300').clearContent();

  var url = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getmarketsummaries";
  var responseAPI = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var parcedData = JSON.parse(responseAPI.getContentText());

  var results = new Array ();

  for(var i in parcedData.result)
    {
      var temp = [];
      for(var j in parcedData.result[i])
      {
        temp.push(parcedData.result[i][j]);
      }
      results.push(temp);
    }

  resultRange = APIPullSheet.getRange(1, 1,results.length,13);
  resultRange.setValues(results);
}
```